# Pandas column multiindex into row multiindex

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a pandas dataframe

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([[i+10*j for i in range(6)] for j in range(5)], index=[f"item{i}" for i in range(5)])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product((["abc", "xyz"], ["one", "two", "three"]))
```

```
      abc           xyz          
      one two three one two three
item0   0   1     2   3   4     5
item1  10  11    12  13  14    15
item2  20  21    22  23  24    25
item3  30  31    32  33  34    35
item4  40  41    42  43  44    45
```

I cannot figure out how to turn first level of column multiindex into row multiindex to get something like following

```
            one two three
item0 abc     0   1     2
      xyz     3   4     5
item1 abc    10  11    12
      xyz    13  14    15
item2 abc    20  21    22
      xyz    23  24    25
item3 abc    30  31    32
      xyz    33  34    35
item4 abc    40  41    42
      xyz    43  44    45
```

any hint appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: `df.stack(level=0)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here you go:

```
df.stack(level=0)
```

Answer (score 3):

As [Quang Hoang](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4238408/quang-hoang) suggested, I would check out [pandas.DataFrame.stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).
The solution should be:

```
df.stack(level=0)
```